# How can you connect Windows phone 7 to a database?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

Im very new to WP7 Development and i have a few questions.

Firstly i would like to know how it is possible to connect to a database on a server?

How can i connect to the local database in the windows phone itself?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local database :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860(v=vs.92).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx

If you want to connect to a remote database, it's not possible. You must use a webservice and JSON (for example)

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to a database on a remote server, you'll have to make use of a webservice. This [**article**](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.1-Local-SQL-Database.aspx) on SilverlightShow.net explains on how to access the local SQL database. Hope this helps!